# Memtrack Module -22 Failure on APK Install

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, apk, logcat

I am able to run my Android app, on my emulator and device, directly from Eclipse. When I generate a signed APK, I am unable to install the APK.

When I run `adb install myapk.apk`, I get this LogCat output:

```
E/        ( 5913): Cannot create code cache directory ./code_cache: Read-only file system. 
E/HAL     ( 5913): load:   module=/system/lib/hw/memtrack.default.so 
E/HAL     ( 5913): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/hw/memtrack.default.so" not found
E/memtrack( 5913): Couldn't load memtrack module (Invalid argument)
E/android.os.Debug( 5913): failed to load memtrack module: -22
```

Any ideas about what `memtrack module: -22` is and how I can resolve this?

Comment: I do not see how this error message could be any more clearer. `-22` is just the code for the `Invalid argument` error

Comment: Ok, thanks. Added a bit to my question "Any ideas what this is and how can I resolve it"?

Answer (score 0):

I had a space in the name of my Eclipse Workbench. I removed the space from my Eclipse Workbench (changed from "My Workbench" to "MyWorkbench"), then generated my APK and was able to install. :-|